# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword NullPointer (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, dom, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

For some reason my `loginAccount()` function will not work. When creating an account with my `createAccount()` function, the DOM elements seem correct as the entered email and password are stored and update my Auth database in Firebase.

However, when trying to use the same login (that I just created) to actually log the user in, apparently Firebase is getting both a `null` email and password from the DOM elements, though the ids are correct.

I'm sure it's something very trivial, yet I have been working to fix this issue for some days now. Any pointers will help!

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
            https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="loginbox">
      <img src="avatar.png" class="avatar" />
      <h1>Login Here</h1>
      <form>

        <p>E-mail</p>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail" id="email" />

        <p>Password</p>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" />

        <button id="signUp" onclick="createAccount()">Sign Up</button>
        <button id="signIn" onclick="loginAccount()">Login</button>
        <button id="signOut" onclick="logOut()">Sign Out</button>

      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyC9AEwx8_GrHRT8uvFoNiK1DOk6IXITnGQ",
  authDomain: "database-993c9.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://database-993c9.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "database-993c9",
  storageBucket: "database-993c9.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "856956039875",
  appId: "1:856956039875:web:27ccd6b0d0bc806135a876",
  measurementId: "G-JJYN70EV99",
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

const auth = firebase.auth();

// Create an account
function createAccount() {
  const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  const pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
}

// Login to an account
function loginAccount() {
  const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  const pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
}

// Logout of an account
function logOut() {
  auth
    .signOut()
    .then(function () {
      // Sign-out successful.
      console.log("signed out.");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
}

auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    console.log("user is signed in!");
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    console.log("no user logged in.");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that your form is submitted before the Firebase  methods are triggered.

As a matter of fact, you declare your button as follows:

```
<button id="signUp" onclick="createAccount()">Sign Up</button>
```

i.e. **without** any `type` attribute.

As detailed in the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) on button types, "the missing value default is the Submit Button state" and "if the type attribute is in the Submit Button state, the element is specifically a submit button".

So, if you add a `button` `type` to your button, as follows, it should solve your problem.

```
<button type="button" id="signUp" onclick="createAccount()">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: You're a savior! Thanks so much.